# How to perform a co-simulation with modelica models?

Tags: python, modelica, openmodelica

I would like to use a modelica model, which is based on an external library, for a co-simulation in another environment like ANSYS, Abaqus, etc. The model should be able to interact with another model. What is the easiest way to co-simulate a modelica model?

For this purpose, the FMU export in openmodelica seems to be the right approach. The problem is that the model is based on an external library and therefore different issues occur (also stated here: https://openmodelica.org/forum/default-topic/2180-libraries-not-included-in-fmu).
In my case, I tried loading the fmu with the FMPY gui (`python -m fmpy.gui`) which resulted in the error:

"Failed to load path/to/haeger_model_win64.fmu. The unit 'ml' of variable 'C_a.V' is not defined."

What works for me now: loading the .mo file with OMPython and simulation in Python. That seems difficult though because I do not know how to interact but only simulate for preset parameters.

You can find the model (haeger_model.mo), the external library (HumanLib.mo) and FMU exports of haeger_model here: https://github.com/xi2pi/LPModelica

The simulation with OMPython works just like explained in the tutorial (https://www.openmodelica.org/doc/OpenModelicaUsersGuide/latest/ompython.html).

The problem is that I do not know how to interact with the model when simulating in Python. An approach with an FMU is preferred.

Comment: The modelica library does not seem to include "extern C" code, which seems to cause the problem described in  https://openmodelica.org/forum/default-topic/2180-libraries-not-included-in-fmu. So which problems occur exactly with FMU export?

Comment: Considering the FMU export, I added a short description about the error to the question and the related files to the repository.